# Which way has the best performance applying several classes to html tags? Angular 2

Tags: angular, ng-class, angular-ng-class

I am building a calendar with prices, I have 3 nested elements:

```
- calendar-layout
-- calendar-month
--- calendar-week
```

In the calendar-week I have to do several calculations for the different styles that can have each day,

```
    // Calendar-week Html
    <div [ngClass]="dayClass(date, i)" *ngFor="let date of days; let i = index;"
         (click)="onClick(date)" [class.not-selectable]="isDayNotSelectable(date)">
       <span class="date-number">{{ date |  date:'d'  }}</span>
       <small class="price" *ngIf="calendarInfo.prices"> {{ getPrice(date) }} </small>
    </div>

// Calendar-week Component
  dayClass(date, i) {
    let cssClass = 'day ';
    if (isDateFrom()) return `${cssClass} selected dateFrom`;
    if (isDateTo()) return `${cssClass} selected dateTo`;
    if (isBeetween()) return `${cssClass} between`;
    if (isReccommended()) cssClass += `recommended `;
    if (isNotPrices()) return cssClass;
    let price = this.calendarInfo.prices[date].price
    cssClass += price <= this.minPrice ? 'low' : price >= this.maxPrice ? 'high' : 'normal';
    return cssClass;
  }
```

As we can see there are a lot of classes that can be placed in the "day" tag.
I've seen that my dayClass () function can be distributed using various approaches with the directive [ngClass], but I don't want to use them without knowing which method is really the most effective.

```
[ngClass]="{'class1':condition1, 'class2': condition2, 'class3':condition3}"
[ngClass.class1]="menu1 || menu2" [ngClass.class2]="(menu1 || menu2) && something">
```

Does anyone know what is the most efficient way to apply classes to an HTML tag having multiple calculations?

Comment: the top one looks best to me, although h I'm not familiar with `${cssCslass| selected dateFrom` syntax. Is there a reason you can't simple return a string for each if statement?

Comment: @Rick 'selected' or 'dateFrom' are just class names. DayClass return all the classes for each day.

Answer (score 1):

Create a pure pipe, that way you pipe will not be called until your date changes. That pipe will return a class for that date and will not get called until your date changes. You current approach is not good as your method will be invoked at each re-render.

Comment: I dont understand, Can you give an example? you mean how do I show the values ​​or how do I apply the classes?

Comment: How you can apply a pure pipe in a html class?

Answer (score 1):

You should always avoid method calls in a template. That's because the rendering engine cannot determine if the function changes value or not given changes in the execution environment variables.

In your example, it cannot know if `dayClass` changes value if `date` changes value. Or if another variable changes (`dayClass` could be unpure and depend on other variables).

Thus, any change detection cycle will require the function to be called, in order to be sure any change in the function value would be caught.

You can witness this behaviour by putting a `console.log` inside your function, you will see it gets executed **a lot** of times.

When you use direct dependencies such as `ngClass` with direct variables, the rendering engine knows when the value changes or not. In your example, that's when `condition1` changes value.

If `condition1` is `variable1 && variable2` for example, the engine will watch for `variable1` and `variable2` values and trigger an update only when those values change (look for information on `ngZone` to understand how it is performed).

So you can see it is much more efficient to avoid function calls and always look for direct evaluation.

Then, `ngClass` or `ngClass.my_class` should have the same perfs, they just manipulate DOM directly.

Comment: Let's say that a double load is carried out, the first places the days of the calendar, and the second when the price of the product is received on that day, other classes are applied when the user clicks on a day. Is your suggestion that I have 10 types of classes so I put them directly in the template?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell without knowing more about your use case. The rule of thumb is to express the semantics of the situation. If there are 10 cases, then you should have 10 classes indeed. A very good framework to think & enforce that in your code is BEM (http://getbem.com/introduction/). It gives good guidelines and will help you answer your question in the specific setting of your use case.

Comment: Naming is not the problem, I am building a calendar for a flight meta-search engine, it shows the days of the month and when it loads the prices, it shows the prices, according to the price range the background will be of one color or another (different class ), there will also be classes in case he selects a day; for these reasons I have so many classes, and I do the calculation of the classes in the component.ts

Comment: Then use one variable per class name, and `[ngClass] = { 'my_class_name': myVariableName, ... }`. Update `myVariableName` depending on the component logic. And you get good perfs as well as good maintainability.